# Kafka Consumer connecting via SSL: how to set the SSLSocketFactory

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka broker and I want to connect my Kafka consumer to it via SSL.

I know there are some properties for the Kafka consumer providing access to the trust and keystore files. Like:

```
ssl.keystore.location=/Users/Documents/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=serversecret
ssl.key.password=serversecret
ssl.truststore.location=/Users/Documents/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=serversecret
```

(I use these properties both at Broker and at Consumer)

As this works I would like to know where I can set a `SSLSocketFactory` in this configuration I'm passing to the `KafkaConsumer`:

```
// other configs
config.setProperty("ssl.keystore.location", "/Users/Documents/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka.server.keystore.jks");
      config.setProperty("ssl.keystore.password", "serversecret");
      config.setProperty("ssl.key.password", "serversecret");
      config.setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", "/Users/Documents/kafka_2.13-2.7.0/kafka.server.keystore.jks");
      config.setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", "serversecret");

_kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
```

But instead I want something like:

```
config.setProperty("ssl.socket.factory", getSslSocketFactory());
_kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(config);
```

I could not find such a property key, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the [property doesn't exist](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs), then it's not able to be set. Additionally, the property values cannot be instantiated objects, anyway

The SSL properties you've specified are the correct way to connect

Comment: You are right. This property does not exist. But I've found `ssl.engine.factory.class`, which I will use now. See also: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=128650952